# Azure Web App for container and swap support

Tags: azure-web-app-service, swap

I search in Microsoft Azure documentation , how i can perform a azure swap between azure web app for container.

In ms documentation , i found topics about azure app Linux and azure app Windows.

Can someone can help me if this feature is supported by Microsoft ?

Answer (score -1):

Azure App Service is simply hosting your container image so there aren't any imposed restrictions (that I'm aware of) towards swapping. To perform the swap, you can also use the [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest) or the portal to perform a swap.